# Get rid of weird hash in url

Tags: php, url

I have this problem: In my .php file i have following a element:

```
<?php
$alias = $videos[$videoIndex]["alias"];
$urlHref = $domain . '/play.php?alias=' . $alias;
echo '<a href="' . $urlHref . '" class="vid">';
?>
```

then href attribute looks like:
http://mypage123.com/template1/play.php?alias=name

But after click on it, it open site with following url:
http://mypage123.com/template1/play.php?alias=name#.U6fudvmSxNo

I don`t get it, why is there this weird hash. Can I get rid of it? Did I something wrong

Comment: It's probably caused by the js on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by change using another plugin (example: for statistics)?

[AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/), for instance appends a hash, and a string to your URLs.

I know it because it has happened to my pages!

Comment: Thank you, this hash was caused by AddThis. And how did you figure it out? Is there any way to have AddThis plugin without this hash?

Comment: Well... I got worried about the security of my site when these `things` appended themselves to my URLs. Also, on a personal note, it was annoying. So I stripped my site to its bare essentials and added my scripts back, one at a time, and was surprised to discover that it was AddThis. I did some googling and confirmed my suspicions. To this day, however, I haven't found a solution to this inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

convert your `$alias` field  to url friendly string first

ie. use

```
$alias=urlencode($alias);
```

Comment: on retrieve use urldecode(); to decode and get original string